# Proofreading API for German texts

Tags: english-to-german, resource

I am an English speaker, looking for a German proofreading API so that I can verify my google translated texts (from English to German). Is there any such tool available and how reliable is it?

I have used [the Spanish proofreading API tool from meaningcloud](https://www.meaningcloud.com/developer/text-proofreading) and I'm looking for something similar to it for German.

Comment: I don't know any API but you may want to check out lang-8.com

Comment: I don't believe, that any automated proofreading tool for any natural language will be reliable within the next few years, so you better double-check the outcome of the Spanish tool you found. Also know that Spanish is thought to be much easier than German, so even if there is a reliable tool for Spanish, it may need some time to make a German tool reliable.

Comment: I just removed the link as it does not make your question better, but may be seen as (unintentional) spam. Welcome to German SE! The [tour] and our [help] are great places to learn more about the site.

Comment: What is an API? For me it is an application programming interface. I can not understand the question?

Comment: @Thomas: I think that is exactly what is being asked about. An application programming interface that has (at least) a function that expects a text written in German, and that will return a data structure indicating any language issues in the text.

Comment: @Stephie: I disagree with the link removal. By removing the link to the tool for Spanish, you have both removed the source for the claim that such a tool exists for any natural language, as well as an example of what the OP is looking for. Wouldn't placing the link on the words "the Spanish proofreading API tool from meaningcloud" be an acceptable solution?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper  Everyone who's interested is just one short google search for "meaningcloud" away from the same content. But as this is a comunity, feel free to roll back.

Comment: @Stephie: Today, yes. If the site goes down or the service is renamed, any future visitor will be left wondering how to find the service. I'll integrate the link in a less conspicuous manner.

Comment: @user83071 your question is missing a lot of context. Do you really let Google translate a text and expect that after doing some automated proofreading it might be acceptable for humans? To me, this feels irresponsible. Maybe you can provide further details as to what the circumstances are?

Answer (score 1):

I just googled in German and found this article: https://www.bitblokes.de/languagetool-3-4-ist-veroeffentlicht-korrekturlesen-mit-open-source/

If you want to google for yourself proofreading is translated as Korrekturlesen.

Answer (score 0):

Statt Google habe DeepL benutzt, und Deine Frage damit übersetzt.

> Ich bin englischsprachig und suche eine deutsche Korrektur-API, damit
>   ich meine google-übersetzten Texte (vom Englischen ins Deutsche)
>   verifizieren kann. Gibt es ein solches Werkzeug und wie zuverlässig
>   ist es?
>
> Ich habe das spanische Korrekturlesen-API-Tool von meaningcloud
>   benutzt und suche nach etwas Ähnlichem für Deutsch.

Das Ergebnis habe ich dann bei https://www.languagetool.org/ eingegeben, und prüfen lassen, wo nur 'meaningcloud' bemängelt wurde, aber das hat mein Browser schon unterkringelt. Welche Api der (chromium) benutzt weiß ich nicht.

Und languagetool hat eine API für Java https://www.languagetool.org/development/

Die negativen Erfahrungen anderer kann ich nicht bestätigen. Ich habe eigene Texte oft prüfen lassen, und die Verbesserungsvorschläge waren, bis  auf Einschränkungen, die die Seite selbst macht (fremdländische Eigennamen zum Beispiel), meist richtig.

Gewiss ist es besser als nichts, und die Entwicklung ist ja auch noch nicht zu Ende.

Answer (score -2):

I am german native speaker, and during writing my thesis I used https://www.languagetool.org a lot to check for grammar and spelling mistakes. Its hard to rate, but from my point of view the corrections are quite good and for german quite mature. It also finds some more subtle meaning differences (One example they give on their website is Saite vs. Seite, the first one being a guitar string, the second one for example a page of a book, or the side of some object).
Languagetool can be used online or offline.

Another website which I sometimes used is http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibpruefung-online. But I am not sure whether they have a public API that can be used for free. They for sure have a paid service or software.

Comment: "I used https://www.languagetool.org a lot to check for grammar and spelling mistakes. Its hard to rate, but from my point of view the corrections are quite good" - I just tried it with a single random sentence that came to my mind: "Der Hund gehört den Nachbarn." This is correctly evaluated as correct. However, the tool also thinks "Der Hund gehört des Nachbarn." and "Der Hund gehört die Nachbarn." are correct. It even accepts "Der Hund gehört Nachbarn die." I wouldn't use that tool for grammar checking.

Comment: languagetool.org failed even for very simple das/dass mistake. I’d not recommend it. The Duden Rechtschreibprüfung though works very well and even detects more advanced mistakes.

Comment: Also die negative Bewertung finde ich fehl am Platze. a) Habe ich selbst schon eine Menge echter Texte überprüft, und das Tool hat vieles gefunden, was falsch war, und richtige Verbesserungen empfohlen. Zweitens erinnere ich mich, dass es eklatante Fehlvorschläge gemächt hätte, außer an Stellen, an denen dies zu erwarten ist, insbes. ausländischen Eigennamen. Desungeachtet wie man das Tool bewertet - eine Einschränkung der Empfehlung soll es ruhig geben, aber es ist m.E. eine richtige Antwort auf die Frage.